# Questions no longer being accepted from my account?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I know that several people have raised this issue before, but I am not sure why this has happened to me. I have not asked many questions on SO, but whenever I have, I've worded them clearly, and if any more detail was needed, I obliged and provided more clarity.

Furthermore, when I did respond to a problem, I was clear and detailed.

The only times that I was down voted significantly was on May 11th, 2013 and January 20th, 2014. On both occasions, either my question or my response to my own question got voted back up; In the first case, I ended up with a positive net vote.

Given these details, why have I been banned? More over, I really don't know what to do to eradicate the ban; I can't add new questions of "high quality" to improve my reputation, as I have been banned. I can't really improve my previous posts anymore, as they have been clearly worded and explained, with code in most cases.

I really rely on SO to figure things out, so any solutions to my problem would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As a heads up, your _overall_ question score is -5. It sounds like it's borderline, but as a suggestion for your Matlab question, work your comments into the question itself. While I only skimmed, it looks like there was a lot of meat in those comments; they should be in the question.

Comment: hichris123, I read that article, focusing particularly on the reversing the ban part, and I looked at my SO history, before I posted this question. I wanted to get a gauge as to how I, given my specific history on SO, could reverse my ban. The only possible solution I can think of would be to follow the advice of ChrisForrence for my post on January 20th, 2014.

Comment: The problem I see here is you have a number of questions, with few positively scored posts.  You have exactly 2 questions >0 net score (and both questions have only 1 upvote each) and only a handful of upvotes across all of your question.  The problem here might not only be the negative posts, but the lack of positive posts as well.  A couple of upvotes might be enough to unban you - however, if you have any deleted posts, that changes the equation.

Comment: The following page is only visible for you (and mods), anything there? http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1672729

Comment: Nope, nothing there. I have no deleted recent questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you're currently banned.

From the look of things, you have quite a few questions, but most of them don't have any votes and - until today - the total score was something like -4. That's not good.

Looks like the folks here on Meta reviewed some of your questions and decided a couple of them weren't so bad after all.

Comment: Yeah, I've been unbanned. Maybe the recent vote ups of some of my past questions by MetaSO users helped my cause. Well, all I can say is thank you guys, and I'll be mindful in the future to create more valuable and informative posts on SO.